# Trouble optimizing Rails queries in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, activerecord

I cannot seem to figure out why my total rendering time is not matching up with my active record time + my views time as listed in my production log.

here is the output from my production log:

Completed 200 OK in 12508ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 46.0ms)

here is the code in my controller:

```
store = Store.find(:vanity_url => params[:vanity_url])
render :json => store.get_pages_with_includes
return false
```

in my Store.rb model, there are two methods that i use to render the json representation of my model with all of it's active relations. here is the eager loading method:

```
def eager_load_pages
    pages = Page.where(:store_id => self.id).includes(
        [{:menu_items => 
            [
                :sizes, 
                {:topping_groups => 
                    {:toppings => :sizes}
                }
            ]
        },
        {:combos => 
            {:combo_item_groups => 
                {:combo_items => 
                    [
                        :sizes,
                        {:topping_groups => 
                            {:toppings => :sizes}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }]
    ).order('position ASC')
    return pages
end
```

and here is the to_json method

```
def get_pages_with_includes
    pages = self.eager_load_pages
    return pages.to_json({:include =>  
        [{:menu_items => 
            {:include =>
                {:topping_groups =>
                    {:include => 
                        {:toppings => 
                            {:include => 
                                :sizes
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {:combos =>
            {:include =>
                {:combo_item_groups => 
                    {:include => 
                        {:combo_items =>
                            {:include => 
                                [:sizes, :topping_groups => 
                                    {:include => 
                                        {:toppings => 
                                            {:include =>
                                                :sizes
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    })
end
```

All of the code is working, and i'm not sure if i can make it more efficient. What i am confused about is why the total page load time is not even close to the amount of time it takes to run my queries. can anyone help me out? Please?? the page should technically be loading in less than 50ms, but its taking 12508ms!

Any help would be much appreciated!

----------UPDATE------------
I ran top from my server and noticed that ruby is occupying 100% of the CPU during these queries. any ideas here? Perhaps this points to the issue...?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the rendering to JSON in your controller is what's taking too long. How many records are you trying to render?
If your Ruby process is taking up all available CPU that means it's not (directly) related to your database, but could be any of these:

- Instantiating objects from your database (if you are retrieving 10,000s of records);
- Rendering these objects to JSON.

Looking at your page load times `(Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 46.0ms)` I'd say it's the rendering to JSON. It doesn't show under `Views` because you're not using any views, but simply calling a render action in the controller directly.

I would suggest you add some tools to your app (such as New Relic RPM) or even simple benchmark methods to find out what's taking so long.

You might also want to consider using a faster JSON parser/renderer instead of the default one. Check out the `multi_json` gem.

Comment: This response is so informative! thank you for clarifying! I will check out the multijson gem, as the json is the only other thing rendering currently. is there a better way to collect all of the active relationships and send them to the view for javascript to collect?

Comment: The database retrieval is ok. Just some unnecessary return statements. Remember that Ruby methods return the value from the last statement if you have no explicit return. So `eager_load_pages` doesn't need the variable assignment and return statement for example. You can check out `jbuilder` or similar JSON view builders instead of using the big `render` call to build proper views. But they will also introduce a slight overhead of course.

Comment: Thats great advice! looking into jbuilder, it seems like it might work for me. the only trouble for me is once i eager-load an object, i really need all of that data to be nested dense arrays. But even after eager-loading, it seems that when i try to build my own arrays it re-runs the queries and causes great latency. thats why ive resorted to the .to_json method. does the jbuilder solve that? meaning, does it interact with eager-loaded models in a way that allows me to not re-run queries?